# Cut one image into smaller pieces

Tags: ruby, image-processing, imagemagick, rmagick

I need to write some ruby script which will help me with big image files. I know basics of imagemagick and rmagick library(ruby), but till now I was doing generally simple things (thumbnailing, adding watermarks etc.) Now I want to cut file with example resoultion 3000/1000px into ten smaller images (3000/100 px). Is it possible? I have no idea which method to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `crop`ping the input image once for each of the output images:

```
output_images =
  (0...10).collect { |i|
    input_image.crop(0, i*100, 3000, 100, true)
  }
```

More generally (but still assuming the Y resolution is divisible by the number of slices):

```
def slice_image_horizontally(image, num_slices)
  slice_height = image.y_resolution / num_slices
  (0...num_slices).collect { |i|
    image.crop(
      0, i * slice_height,
      image.x_resolution, slice_height,
      true # reset image offset
    )
  }
end
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#crop

Answer (score 1):

```
10.times do |slice|
  system "convert example.jpg -crop x100+0+#{slice * 100} +repage example#{slice}.jpg"
end
```

EDIT: Yeah, I guess RMagick is cooler :)

Comment: Yeah, I considered suggesting `convert`, but Arti specifically said to use Ruby and RMagick. And `+repage` is a good catch; I've added something equivalent to my answer.